# UnicodeDecodeError - XML to CSV

Tags: python

I'm getting an error while converting xml (from a url) to csv. The code was working fine until yesterday but for some reason it's giving error below!

Unicode Decode Error: 'char map' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1543041: character maps to

It would be a great help if someone can suggest someting)

Comment: Hi Majid and welcome. Consider posting a snippet of the code and the operating system that you are using, since the encodings vary between OS and it might require you to open the file on a different encoding. Cheers!

Comment: The error complains that the text file you tried to load uses the wrong encoding. How do you open the file? Most XML files are stored as UTF8 but Python's `open` doesn't use UTF-8 by default. You need to specify `encoding='utf-8'`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: df = pd.read_json('data.json')
    path = Path(r'data.json')
    with path.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
    new_data = data['list']['property']
    df = pd.json_normalize(new_data)

Here is the code,  I was using the same code for more than a year and it was working fine. Don't know what happened with the xml link(https://expert.propertyfinder.ae/feed/eandt/privatesite/2a6f63ebeda1ec656a01d28865301eda) it suddenly started giving error